# How to call data from Stateful class to State

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Stateful class and I wanna took "Data" from Stateful class to State class

Here is my code:

```
class PlayMode extends StatefulWidget {
  final Data data;
  PlayMode({this.data}); // Pass this to State class

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new PlayModeState();
  }
}
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `PlayModeState` class, simply use

```
widget.data
```